# Jmeter 3.0 with Ant Task for DashBoard generation

Tags: ant, jmeter

With JMeter 3.0 Dashboard generation has become more interesting 
  and powerful.

a) How to use the following using 'Ant target' ?

**`jmeter -g /path/to/jtl/file -o /where/you/want/to/store/dashboard`**

b) How to Attach the Asset Validation Framework to the Dashboard.

This would help me generate Dashboard reports using Ant Tasks.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option would be to use ant's **exec** command.

```
<target name="generate-new-report">
    <exec executable="${jmeter.home}/bin/jmeter.bat">
        <arg value="-g"/>
        <arg value="/path/to/jtl/file"/>
        <arg value="-o"/>
        <arg value="/where/you/want/to/store/dashboard"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```